# Fastest way to execute a delete query in large table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a large table and a simple delete query that takes about 84 seconds to delete 13k matching records from the table.  Below are the JPA queries tested so far.

```
delete from PlanItems p where p.jobId = :jobid
```

Other variation tested:

```
delete from PlanItems p where p.jobId in (select pi.jobId from PlanItems pi where pi.jobId = :jobid)
```

Given that the table `PlanItems` already have an index defined on column `jobId` and there's only one foreign key exist in this table, what are the options to fasten up my delete query? I'm using `postgres` with spring jpa for my backend service. Note that I don't want to truncate and insert into this table since there are many users who operate on same data in parallel. I checked multiple posts for this matter, tried out all possible options as mentioned.

Query execution plan details:
Query 1->
[image]
Query 2->
[image]

This is how I measure the latency:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
planItemsRepository.deleteByJobId(jobId);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("Took around "+(end-start)+" milliseconds to delete all plan items records by jobId "+jobId);
```

And the repository logic is as simple as below:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from PlanItems p where p.jobId in (select pi.jobId from PlanItems pi where pi.jobId = :jobid) ")
int deleteByJobId(@Param("jobid") long jobId);
```

I would like to know how to reduce the latency to half way mark or even lesser.

Comment: if its a background job , then try deleting data in chunks. if you have column like added_date or modified_date then filter data on basis of date else get ids first 1000 or 500 rows and delete them and so on.

Comment: Does the other table have an index on the column(s) that are part of the foreignkey constraint? Note it is good practice to include all relevant DDL and the output of `explain analyze` when asking about query performance.

Comment: Maybe **other** tables have Foreign Keys to this planitems table?

Comment: @wildplasser
two other tables have foreign keys to `planitems` table. But those are small tables.

Comment: @Eelke
Yes, that table has an index too on the same column.
I'm only concerned about delete operation here. I logged the latency to verify the same.

Comment: @Yogi
Deleting chunk by chunk: Seems like I need to write a procedure for this?

Comment: @Eelke
Updated post with more info on query execution.

Answer (score 1):

If this query is taking a long time:

```
delete from PlanItems p where p.jobId = :jobid
```

*and* you have an index on `PlanItmes(jobId)` -- where `jobId` is the first column in the index -- then you need to consider other issues.

1. Are there cascading foreign key constraints that use `jobId`?  If so the cascades may impact those tables -- and if they are cascading deletes, then deleting those rows may affect more tables.
2. Is there a delete trigger on the table?  If so, your "simple" deletes may be doing a lot more work than you think.
3. Is there a heavy load on the system?  If so, the time may simply be waiting for an opportunity to delete the rows.
4. Are materialized views built on the table?  If so, they might be being refreshed.

If none of these are the case, then it might be an issue on how you are measuring the elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm going through your comments, I updated my post above with more details.