# How to perform filtered table move in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

For example, in Oracle, we can move the table, filtering out rows with an ID value greater than 50 as shown below:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MOVE ONLINE INCLUDING ROWS WHERE id <= 50;
```

How can I achieve the same in Postgres? I was not able to find relevant docs for the same. Is the feature available in Postgres?

Comment: Move the table to where?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Actually, I'm trying to mock delete query on table `t1`. Since the table is large, delete query is very slow. 

I was referring to this guide:
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-delete-millions-of-rows-fast-with-sql

Comment: Wow, I never new an ALTER TABLE statement can also DELETE rows. But there is no equivalent in Postgres. You will have to run a regular DELETE statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Is there anyway I can reduce latency of my delete query in postgres? I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025309/fastest-way-to-execute-a-delete-query-in-large-table-in-postgresql

I would like to know your thoughts on this.